# javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget optional queryparam

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client, query-string

I'm calling a downstream that supports a bunch of optional queryparams.

Likewise I only sometimes want to add those queryparams, but doing this gets kind of annoying

```
public Map<Subject, Role> getGrantsForResource(
        final String propertyId,
        final boolean filterByRole
) {
    final WebTarget resource;
    if (filterByRole) {
        resource = ramClient
                .path("/v1/resource/{resource}/grants")
                .resolveTemplate("resource", "resource.property." + propertyId)
                .queryParam("role", "role.23"); //add queryparam
    } else {
        resource = ramClient
                .path("/v1/resource/{resource}/grants")
                .resolveTemplate("resource", "resource.property." + propertyId);
                //don't add queryparam
    }
```

and in case of multiple optional queryparams leads to an explosion of combinations.

Always adding the queryparams but making the values empty string or null when they're not needed doesn't work either - adding a queryparam with value null results in an NPE and sending in an empty string results in the query parameter being added, but with no value.

I came up with this workaround

```
public Map<Subject, Role> getGrantsForResource(
        final String propertyId,
        final Map<String, String> queryParams
) {

    WebTarget resource = ramClient
            .path("/v1/resource/{resource}/grants")
            .resolveTemplate("resource", "resource.property." + propertyId);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : queryParams.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue() == null) {
            //don't add queryparam
        } else {
            resource = resource.queryParam(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }
```

but surely there's a better way of doing it?

Comment: Using the map looks fine to me. Don't think you will find any API to make this look ay cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the nulls when constructing the WebTarget.

```
public Map<Subject, Role> getGrantsForResource(
    final String propertyId,
    final Map<String, String> queryParams) {

    WebTarget resource = ramClient
        .path("/v1/resource/{resource}/grants")
        .resolveTemplate("resource", "resource.property." + propertyId);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() != null) {
              webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    
    // use webTarget ...
}
```